# Howto Integrate vendor docs in phpdoc?

Tags: php, composer-php, phpdoc

Is there a way to configure [phpdoc](http://phpdoc.org) so that it will also generate docs for all installed vendor apps with [composer](https://getcomposer.org)?

Why? Well because it would be very nice to have just one doc enviroment wich provides all the docs with the current version of your app and all of your vendor apps. You can just search your own doc enviroment to check out how you should speak to an object belonging to laravel or Zend or whatever you need.

My current phpdoc.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpdoc>
    <title>App title</title>
    <parser>
        <default-package-name>RootNamespace\app\</default-package-name>
        <target>docs</target>
        <markers>
            <item>TODO</item>
            <item>FIXME</item>
        </markers>
        <extensions>
            <extension>php</extension>
            <extension>php3</extension>
            <extension>phtml</extension>
        </extensions>
        <visibility></visibility>
    </parser>
    <transformer>
        <target>docs</target>
    </transformer>
    <logging>
        <level>warn</level>
        <paths>
            <default>{APP_ROOT}/data/log/{DATE}.log</default>
            <errors>{APP_ROOT}/data/log/{DATE}.errors.log</errors>
        </paths>
    </logging>
    <files>
        <ignore>src/View/*</ignore>
        <ignore>tests/*</ignore>
        <directory>src</directory>
    </files>
</phpdoc>
```

Please don't answer with just "No". Somebody must've figured this out.

Comment: Assuming your `phpdoc.xml` is in your top-level directory, then I should think: `<files><directory>vendor/**/*</directory><ignore>vendor/bin</ignore><ignore>vendor/composer</ignore></files>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Comment from @bishop worked for me:

Assuming your `phpdoc.xml` is in your top-level directory then this works:

```
<files>
    <directory>vendor/**/*</directory>
    <directory>src</directory>
    <ignore>vendor/bin</ignore>
    <ignore>vend‌​or/composer</ignore>
    <ignore>src/View/*</ignore>
    <ignore>tests/*</ignore>
</files>
```

Comment: How can this be done in reverse; ignore all the vendor directories except certain ones, rather than ignoring certain ones?